# Multiplying vector by the covariance matrix only known approximately

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix, maximum-entropy

([cross-posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3837579/multiplying-vector-by-exy-where-only-ex-ey-ex-odot-y-are-know) on math.SE)

For random variable $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$ and vector $v$, I need to perform the following operation on a $d \times d$ covariance matrix $E[xy']$

$$T(v)=E[xy']v$$

The issue is that the expected matrix $E[xy']$ is too large to represent in memory ($d$=1 million), so only some of its statistics have been collected and I need to perform this operation approximately. One factorization keeps track of $E[x]$ and $E[y']$, so then my multiplication can be performed as follows

$$E[xy']v\approx E[x]E[y']v$$

However, in addition to $E[x]$ and $E[y]$, I have also collected the following statistic $E[x\odot y]$, ie, the diagonal of $E[xy']$, how should my matrix multiplication incorporate this statistic?

The generic approach would be to use maxent principle to obtain maximum entropy distribution subject to given moment constraints, and multiply by its covariance matrix, the question is -- can this be done much cheaper than multiplying by the full covariance matrix $E[xy']$?